# sql to return list of parents and their nested child collections

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I've googled this for hours but couldn't get a satisfactory answer. Lets say I have a table `tblCustomers` and a related `tblOrders`. This is your typical parent - child relationship where you can have only one unique customer in `tblCustomers` but the customer can have multiple orders in `tblOrders`. Now in C# I have the Customer and Orders objects like this

```
public class Customer
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set; }

   //Nested child Order collection
   public List<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public int CustomerId { get; set; }
   public string ItemName { get; set; }
   public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}
```

How do you return a List of Customers and their nested Orders in one transaction? I have tried this sql

```
var sql = @"SELECT c.*,
            (SELECT TOP 100 o.* FROM [dbo].[tblOrders] AS o 
             WHERE c.Id = o.CustomerId
             ORDER BY o.ItemName ASC) AS Orders
           FROM [dbo].[tblCustomers] AS c";

var listOfCustomers = dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<Customer>(sql).ToList();
```

but I get this error

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the
>   subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Anyone spot an error in my sql (*sql is not my cup of tea*) or know of a better sql that will accomplish the same in one transaction?

Comment: @tinka I know Linq to Sql and EF generate sql statements behind the scenes. How efficient would such a generated sql in regards to the results I'm looking for? I'd also like to use the sql in a stored procedure for other apps hence I don't want to be tied to Linq to Sql

Answer (score 0):

we can't use `*` in subquery we have to specify 1 column The nested query must return only one column for comparison

```
SELECT c.*,
            (SELECT TOP 100 o.CustomerId  FROM [dbo].[tblOrders] AS o 
             WHERE c.Id = o.CustomerId
             ORDER BY o.ItemName ASC) AS Orders
           FROM [dbo].[tblCustomers] AS c
```

we can make it like that also

```
SELECT c.*
FROM [dbo].[tblCustomers] AS c
WHERE c.Id in
(SELECT TOP 100 o.CustomerId  FROM [dbo].[tblOrders] AS o 
c.Id = o.CustomerId
ORDER BY o.ItemName ASC)
```

using `Linq`

```
var CustOrd = (from c in dbContext.Customers
                  join o in dbContext.Orders on c.Id equals o.CustomerId 
                  select new
                  {
                      c,
                      o
                  }).ToList();
```

Comment: Ok didn't know that. But still this doesn't help me get back all my customers and their nested orders in one transaction. I can get all customers first then iterate through customers and query the orders for each customer, but this means multiple db calls which is inefficient.

Comment: @MosesMachua i tried to solve your problem which you mention in Q if you want all orders try: `select c.*,o.* from customers c join orders o on c.id=o.CustomerId`

Comment: While the error is gone now, all I get back is list of customers totalling the number of orders in `tblOrders` but all the properties are empty